# data between two dates in texbox:error in code

Tags: c#

**date textbox to textbox**
when in write date in text box the corrs data between ***two dates come in data grid***
**my code is:**

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection cs = new SqlConnection("Data Source=IRIS-CSG-174;Initial Catalog=library_system;Integrated Security=True");
        cs.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between=" + textBox1.Text+""+"and"+ textBox2.Text +"", cs);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "lib_issue_details");
        dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("text", ds, "lib_issue_details.book_issue_on"));
```

It shows error that Incorrect syntax near '='.
help me in this code...thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4):

I think this line

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between=" + textBox1.Text+""+"and"+ textBox2.Text +"", cs);`

Should be like this:

`SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between " + textBox1.Text + " and " + textBox2.Text, cs);`

Alternatively, a better way would to use [parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between @date1 and @date2", cs);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@date1", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters["@date1"].Value = textBox1.Text;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@date2", SqlDbType.DateTime);
cmd.Parameters["@date2"].Value = textBox1.Text;
```

I would probably look at using a [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) instead of text boxes as well.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the "=" from the query
It should be `where book_issue_on between date1 and date2` no need for the '=' sign

Your code should be

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from dbo.lib_issue_details where book_issue_on between " + textBox1.Text+""+" and "+ textBox2.Text +"", cs);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but now it is giving error when i remove"=":An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'between2011'.

Comment: You need a space between the word between and the = sign. The best thing is to use parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Use command parameters. If only for security ([SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection))

Some examples:

- [Lesson 06: Adding Parameters to Commands](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson06.aspx)
- [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx)